# Error requesting Linkedin access/application token

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to get access to the application token but whenever I put information in the request body I get send back

```
{
    "error": "access_denied",
    "error_description": "This application is not allowed to create application tokens"
}
```

Also using the OAuth 2.0 tools to request a new access token gives an error

I tried accessing https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken with grant_type=client_credentials, client_id=xxx and client_secret=xxx expecting back a token